# CSS Style issue using Express.js

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const request= require("request");
    const app = express();
    var path = require("path");



    app.use("/fonts", express.static(path.join("fonts")));
    app.use("/images" , express.static(path.join("images")));

    app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css.main.css'));

    app.get("/", function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'index.html'));
    });



    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("server is up and running")
    })
```

Here, I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. My CSS and fonts and images are not working. [image: My folder structure]

Comment: Did you add bootstrap link in index.html?

Comment: @TanmoySarkar yes it is..